# Are Private Messages available in Salesforce Communities Napili Template?

Tags: community, customer-community, napili

In the Napili template, there's an option for Enable Private Messages:

[image]

However, I cannot seem to locate how one sends and receives private messages. How does one go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private messaging is currently not available in Napili template .I had reached to SFDC on this and there is no way currently .Possibility that they will add it in coming releases but no guarantee and safe harbour.

You can build lightning components to achieve the same functionality .It will require additional effort .

Meanwhile lets vote for this Idea

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Lj9dAAC

[image]

Comment: Thanks again, Mohith. I am finding that with Salesforce Communities, many features are implied to exist, but really don't. Seriously, why show a checkbox for "Enabled private messaging" in the Napili template by default, when this feature simply doesn't exist. Same is true with Chatter Answers, Chatter Questions, and Ideas. None for these features work, unless you are using the Salesforce Classic Tabs template for communities. Docs show screenshots of these featuring working in what looks like Napili, but they don't.

Comment: Its for Salesforce classic .I agree with you and need some great documentation around this .Happy to see you come with questions here and that documents most of things with my answer